# Inserting data with ng-if into ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

Using AngularJS, I have a transaction table where the user can have multiple items per transaction, and for each item, they have the option to leave a reference. For the items where they don't want to leave a reference for, replacement text `[No client reference provided]` is to be inserted, which is done on other pages through a `data-ng-if` condition like so:

```
<span class="txt-grey" data-ng-if="item.clientRef == ''">[No client reference provided]</span>
<span data-ng-if="item.clientRef !== ''">{{item.clientRef}}</span>
```

If there is only one item in the transaction, the reference/replacement text is shown as a string, if there are multiple items per transaction, they are inserted into a select drop-down like so:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.tableData" data-ui-sref-active="active">
    <td>
        <span data-ng-if="item.renewalUIs.length === 1" data-ng-repeat="patent in item.renewalUIs">
            <span data-ng-if="patent.patentUI.patentApplicationNumber.length">
                {{patent.patentUI.patentApplicationNumber}}
            </span>
        </span>
        <select data-ng-if="item.renewalUIs.length > 1" data-ng-options="item.patentUI.patentApplicationNumber for item in item.renewalUIs" data-ng-model="$ctrl.patentAppData.defaultSelect" data-ng-if="" data-ng-change="$ctrl.transactionListFilter($ctrl.patentAppData.defaultSelect, 'patentAppFilter', item.id)" class="pill-radius form-control font-body">
            <option value="">Multiple</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The issue is, if no client reference is provided, the drop-down menu is blank. I need to apply the same logic (as the `span` elements) of providing a condition and inserting `[No client reference provided]` if no value is provided.

***Question***

Is there a way to combine `ng-if` and `ng-options` to check whether a value has been provided, and if not, insert replacement text?

Answer (score 1):

First you may have several selects:

```
<select ng-if="condition" ng-options="...">
<select ng-if="!condition" ng-options="...">
```

Second, you may have condition on option:

```
<select ng-options="item.patentUI.patentApplicationNumber for item in item.renewalUIs">
<option ng-if="!item.renewalUIs.length">empty option</option>
```

Both ways above may have some side effects depending on your concrete way of data change/animation/old browser support etc. Last is most flexible - keep your view as simple as possible:

```
<select ng-options="item.patentUI.patentApplicationNumber for item in $ctrl.options[item.id]" ng-model="$ctrl.patentAppData.defaultSelect" class="pill-radius form-control font-body">
        </select>
```

where `$ctrl.options[item.id]` is your model for options - but you will need to update it manually in controller on all required changes.